# When using navsat_transform_node, isn't it a problem to use IMU yaw to compute transform between map and base_link?

Tags: navigation, mapping, navsat-transform-node, base-link, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

In [this video from Tom Moore](https://www.osrfoundation.org/tom-moore-working-with-the-robot-localization-package/) at time 12:36, I can see that he sets IMU yaw to true. The consequence of this is that as soon as the robot is started, there is an non zero angle between base_link and map, with X axis of map pointing to the east (except if robot is facing east of course).
I think there is an inconsistency with what this picture says [image description http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/_images/figure1.png](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/_images/figure1.png). I understand here that map and base_link should be aligned at start so that navsat_transform_node can properly compute a transform between utm and map, thanks to the theta angle given by the IMU.
Having map and base_link aligned is mandatory because the IMU reports the angle between base_link and east.

Can you please point me my mistake, and if there is no mistake, how should map and base_link be related when using navsat_transform_node ?

Thank you

Yvon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265240/when-using-navsat_transform_node,-isn%27t-it-a-problem-to-use-imu-yaw-to-compute-transform-between-map-and-base_link-?/) by [Yvonnn](https://answers.ros.org/users/30942/yvonnn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah, so I think the issue here is one if being descriptive vs. prescriptive. In the image from `navsat_transform_node`, all I am trying to do is visualize the parameters in question and the need for them. However, note that the drawing is *not* inconsistent with the use case of fusing yaw in your EKF state estimate. At time `t0`, the robot's state really *is* as the picture above shows, since you have not received an IMU measurement when the node starts. It just so happens that the EKF doesn't publish the state at time `t0`, which would just be a zero state (unless you specify a starting state).

However, it doesn't actually matter. `navsat_transform_node` does *not* assume that your robot's first pose is (0, 0). Imagine a scenario in which you start your robot indoors (without GPS signal), and then drive around for a while, and then go outside. We have to be able to support that use case, and we do. `navsat_transform_node` considers the robot's pose at the time it receives its initial GPS fix when it calculates the *map*->*utm* transform.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0